# Python NLTK: Count list of word and make probability with valid English words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a dirty document which includes invalid English words, numbers, etc.
I just want to take all valid English words and then calculate the ratio of my list of words to the total number of valid English words.

For example, if my document has the sentence:

```
sentence= ['eishgkej he might be a good person. I might consider this.']
```

I want to count only `"he might be a good person. I might consider this"` and count `"might"`.

So, I got the answer 2/10.

I am thinking about using the below code. However, I need to change not the line `features[word] = 1` but the count of features...

```
 all_words = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in reader.words() if w.lower() not in english_sw)

 def document_features(document):
     document_words = set(document)
     features = {}
     for word in word_features:
         if word in document_words:
             features[word] = 1
         else:
             features[word]=0
     return features
```

Comment: Have you tried looking up the words in a dictionary, e.g. WordNet?

Comment: Where are `english_sw` and `word_features` defined?

Comment: oh english_sw is "dictionary" such as WordNet as lasmans said..

Comment: and word_features is at this point "might". I just assumed there is something..

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.FreqDist-class.html#count) you can use `count(self, sample)` to  return the count of a word in a `FreqDist` object. So I think you want something like:

```
 for word in word_features:
     if word in document_words:
         features[word] = all_words.count(word)
     else:
         features[word]= 0
```

Or you could use indexing, i.e. `all_words[word]` should return the same as `all_words.count(word)`

If you want the frequency of the word you can do `all_words.freq(word)`